# Updating a normalized Redux store entity

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the following store structure:

```
"entity": {
  "byId": {
    "id0001": {
      "name": "first"
    },
    "id0002": {
      "name": "second"
    }
  }
  "allIds": ["id0001", "id0002"]
```

And I have 2 associated reducers (`entityById` and `entityAllIds`). When I create a new entity, I dispatch a `CREATE_ENTITY` action that is caught by both reducers. The ID of the object is set in the `entityById` reducer using a `UUID` generator module.

The problem is that I set ID in the first reducer, but I also need it pushed in the second reducer.

What do I do? Do I generate the ID outside the reducer (in the component on click or container right before dispatch?) or do I join the two reducers into one?

I went with separate reducers because I wanted to keep things clean and I only needed the `allIds` reducer for ADD and DELETE actions.

#### Edit

I found a third solution: generate the ID in the action creator, like in the

[redux todo list example](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html).

Comment: Since UUID generation *might* be considered a side-effect, I would go with your third solution. I think it's also more straight-forward and will allow you to keep reducers small and simple.

Comment: You should create the ID in the ActionCreator or before. The reducer should not handle that logic.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up going with the third solution. First one of you to post an answer will get an accept!

Comment: @Norbert I know this question is a few years old but if you still normalize data in reducers try using https://github.com/brietsparks/normalized-reducer